# How do I resolve this CSS display issue?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with CSS `display:none` for mobile queries as exemplified in code below. When screen width is reduced to `600px` the `@media` query rules remove a div that should be displayed.

div `.mobile-content` is being removed together with div `.desktop-content` under `@media` rules. The mobile screen becomes blank as both divs are removed instead of `.desktop-content`

I suspect its a simple issue...how do I fix this?

Here is the code...

```css
.desktop-content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mobile-content {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .mobile-content {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .desktop-content {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Desktop & Mobile</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="desktop-content">
      <p>This is desktop content only</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-content">
      <p>This is mobile content only</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: just add the style `display: block;` to the `.mobile-content` in @media query. It's still displayed `none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an extra media query if it is okay for you or just add `display:block;` to your `.mobile-content{}` inside `@media (max-width:600px){}` as suggested by the other answers.

It will solve the problem. The code will be:

```css
@media all and (min-width:600px){
  .mobile-content{
    display:none;
}

}

.desktop-content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
}



@media all and (max-width:600px) {
  .mobile-content {
    
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .desktop-content {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Desktop & Mobile</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="desktop-content">
      <p>This is desktop content only</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-content">
      <p>This is mobile content only</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` under the `font-size: 28px;` like this

```
@media(max-width:600px) {
  .mobile-content {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-content {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue isnt that both are being removed. It's that the mobile isnt being displayed in the first place. Your code should look something like this:

```css
.desktop-content {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mobile-content {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width:600px) {
  .mobile-content {
    display: block;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;

  }
  .desktop-content {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Desktop & Mobile</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="desktop-content">
      <p>This is desktop content only</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-content">
      <p>This is mobile content only</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```